# How to get a specific child in .jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to get a specific child?

```
<div class="tab">
    <input name="css-tabs" checked>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="shi1"></ div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="trainings-list">
            </ div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the `training-list` element depends on the check input!

I try with `.next()`,`.child()`,`.find()` but I have not managed to get the desired result.

And with `$('input[name="css-tabs"]:checked')` i get the input!

Comment: `$('input[name="css-tabs"]:checked').next('.trainings-list')` should work

Comment: @Roy no it won't - `.trainings-list` is not a sibling of the checkbox.

Comment: @Utkanos this way, sorry. `$('input[name="css-tabs"]:checked').next('.tab-content').find('.trainings-list')`

Comment: There is a lot of ways to get to you element - one way could be `$('input[name="css-tabs"]:checked').closest('.tab').find('.trainings-list');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the `.trainings-list` element *relative* to the checked input, you need this:

```
$('input[name="css-tabs"]:checked + .tab-content .trainings-list')
```

It's all about knowing the relationships in the hierarchy of your HTML. How can we get from the input to the relative `.trainings-list` element? Well, we have to go across to the input's sibling, `.tab-content`, and then we find `.trainings-list` *within* that.

Answer (score 0):

the `.next()` method allows us to search through the immediately following sibling

the `.find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree

https://jsfiddle.net/ncybkxa6/

```
var training_list = $('input[name="css-tabs"]:checked').next('.tab- 
content').find('.trainings-list').html();

 alert(training_list)
```

Comment: please add context so all understand why this answer would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Check this **working way**

```
$('input[name="css-tabs"]:checked').next('.tab-content').find('.trainings-list')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9m1ch2u/

```js
alert($('input[name="css-tabs"]:checked').next('.tab-content').find('.trainings-list').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
    <input name="css-tabs" checked type="checkbox" />
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="shi1"></ div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="trainings-list">
                working!
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```